# Exception thrown inside an empty catch block

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception

I have the following weird error;
An exception thrown on the empty Catch block!

Any ideas how this is possible and how to fix it?

Thanks!

[image: blah]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i think i got it...

```
For Each mediaPlayerID In _attachedDevices.Values.GroupBy(Function(t)t.MediaPlayerInfo.ID).Distinct()
    Try
        fileSystemPerMediaPlayerId.Add(mediaPlayerID.Key, New FileSystemOnDevice())
    Catch
    End Try
Next
```

The problem is caused by a null variable in the lambda expression inside the GroupBy method...

The compiler just pointed the wrong line..

Answer (score 2):

It tried and failed, but there was nothing in the catch to handle it, hence the error `NullReferenceException was unhandled`.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible,
Somewhere there must be "Throw new ..Exception(...)"

Comment: @user1179861 But there was a null reference exception in the application in the `Try` block that was unhandled. That's what your error is saying. It's saying it tried to run your code and failed, and the exception (from failing to run) was not handled.

Comment: But that is what catch block is all about - handling the exception (or ignoring it in this case).

Comment: @user1179861 Exactly. You didn't handle it in this case, that's why it's unhandled.

Comment: what is 'handling'? 
how the compiler knows if it 'handled' or not?
and if i don't care about this exception, how should i ignore it?

Comment: @user1179861 if you don't want to handle exceptions, don't put the function in a `Try...Catch`. One way might be to try `if(fileSystemPerMediaPlayerId.Add([...])) [...] else /* do something else */`

Comment: I'm really sorry but i must be rude...
I wasn't sure, but now i am: u don't know what you're saying...
Dictionary<>.Add is void method which doesn't return any value.
And anyway, Catch block should suppress any exceptions thrown...

Comment: @user1179861 I also apologize, but it's the other way around :) - I can't see the full code, but it looks like in your try block you're calling a function that's returning `NULL` as you stated, and as the error states. If it's trying to do something that's returning nothing (null) back to it, then it has no idea if it successfully executed, which is why the whole try block is wrong, hence the error.

Comment: @user1179861 I'll try to explain it in simpler terms: you tried something, it returned `NULL` - that's an exception because it thinks it failed because it got back `NULL`. Then it tried to run the catch, but there's nothing there to handle the exception. If you don't understand, then I'm not sure what to tell you.

Comment: returning null is not a problem,
trying to manipulate or access variable that is null is a problem..
and again, my Catch block should cause the compiler to skip the try block in case of any exception..

Comment: Pressing 'View Details' probably will show more info on the issue.